# Library Error for Ruby/QT

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4, kde4

Trying to create a `QtRuby` application, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/Qt/qtruby4.rb:2144: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-03-03) [x86_64-linux]
```

I am running a `64-bit` version of Novell OpenSUSE 11 with `DKE4` and `Qt`

Comment: Posted to document my own fix.

Comment: Don't forget that you can mark your own answer as the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with: require 'Qt'

Because of the 64bit libraries, instead you need to use:

require 'korundum4'

Reference: http://www.sheepguardingllama.com/?p=2661